# [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dataMoviesGenres.results[randomIndex]')]

Tags: reactjs

I have this error in a React-Native project,

```
[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dataMoviesGenres.results[randomIndex]')]
```

I want to fetch datas from an URL, but there's a problem with the following line :

```
const randomItem = dataMoviesGenres.results[randomIndex];
```

The URL returns me JSON, with 20 movies in the array results, and I want to get a random movie among these 20, so I put a random number to get results[randomNumber}

```
async toggleStart() {
    this.setState({
      started: !this.state.started
    });

    const randomPage = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1;
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;

    if (this.state.started) {
      try {
        const dataMoviesGenres = await axios.get(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=fr-FR&include_adult=false&with_genres=${this.state.categorieChosenId}&sort_by=popularity.desc&page=${randomPage}`
        );

        const randomItem = dataMoviesGenres.results[randomIndex]; <-- PROBLEM WITH THIS
        console.log("dataMoviesGenres ", dataMoviesGenres);

        this.setState({
          randomMovie: randomItem
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error ", error);
      }
    }
    console.log("API KEY ", API_KEY);
    console.log("randomPage ", randomPage);
    console.log("randomIndex ", randomIndex);
  }
```

And here's the URL if you want to see the details of the JSON response

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=381e8c936f62f2ab614e9f29cad6630f&language=fr-FR&include_adult=false&with_genres=28&sort_by=popularity.desc&page=1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Response schema](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) into **axios** doc, you are trying to access data in a bad way. The error tells you that there is no field called `results` into `dataMoviesGenres` constant.

Just replace that line with

```js
const randomItem = dataMoviesGenres.data.results[randomIndex];
```

Real results are into `data` field.